# How to remove specific commits from Git?

Tags: git

I want to remove few commits from my remote repository. I have few commits like this in my repo:

```
commits    messages

abcd123    some message
xyze456    another commit message
98y65r4    this commit is not required
987xcrt    this commit is not required
bl8976t    initial commit
```

I want to remove commit  `98y65r4` and `987xcrt` from my repo. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

There are two alternatives to this: the safe one that leaves you with a dirty git history, or the unsafe one that leaves you with a clean git history. You pick:

## Option 1: Revert

You can tell git to "Revert a commit". This means it will introduce a change that reverts each change you made in a commit. You would need to execute it twice (once per commit):

```
git revert 98y65r4
git revert 987xcrt
```

This solution will leave your git history like this (you can execute `gitk --all` to see a graphical representation of the state of your repo):

```
2222222    revert of 987xcrt: this commit is not required
1111111    revert of 98y65r4: this commit is not required
abcd123    some message
xyze456    another commit message
98y65r4    this commit is not required
987xcrt    this commit is not required
bl8976t    initial commit
```

Then you can push the new 2 commits to your remote repo:

```
git push
```

This solution is safe because it does not make destructive operations on your remote repo.

## Option 2: Interactive rebase

You also can use an interactive rebase for that. The command is:

```
git rebase -i bl8976t
```

In it, you are telling git to let you select which commits you want to mix together, reorder or *remove*.

When you execute the command an editor will open with a text similar to this:

```
pick    bl8976t    initial commit
pick    987xcrt    this commit is not required
pick    98y65r4    this commit is not required
pick    xyze456    another commit message
pick    abcd123    some message
```

Just go on and delete the lines you don't want, like this:

```
pick    bl8976t    initial commit
pick    xyze456    another commit message
pick    abcd123    some message
```

Save the file and close the editor.

So far, this has only modified the local copy of your repository (you can see the tree of commits with `gitk --all`).

Now you need to push your changes to your repo, which is done with a "push force", but before you execute the command bear in mind that **push force is a destructive operation, it will overwrite the history of your remote repository and can cause merge troubles to other people working on it**. If you are ok and want to do the push force, the command is:

```
git push -f
```

Comment: interactive rebase helped me more than once..

Comment: If I have two developers working on a shared remote repo and one of them committed to the wrong branch and merged those changes up to the integration level branch, is there a way that I can fix their issues? The history for those commits lie in the two other developers local repos, not in mine.

Comment: On your final point, you could use `git push --force-with-lease`, to check if there are any differences between your branch and the upstream branch, if anyone else has pushed any changes in the meantime.

Comment: interactive rebase saved my marriage