# Removing one of many commits from master branch keeping rest of commits

Tags: git

I have like 20 commits and I need to remove one of the commits (commit #20). I have tried:

`git reset --hard hashID`

but it is moving the head to that particular head:

`HEAD is now at someID`

I don't want to change the head I just want to remove those changes.

What can I do? How can I remove that particular commit and keep the rest of the commits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove specific commits from GIt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46724078/how-to-remove-specific-commits-from-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind **rewriting the history of the branch**:

```
git checkout hashID~1 # stand on the previous revision
git cherry-pick hashID..the-branch # replay all revisions after the one I want to remove
# if you like the results
git branch -f the-branch
```

Comment: how I'll do if I want to keep the history ?

Comment: If you want to keep that revision in history, then what you are asking for is `git revert hashID` which will revert the changes introduced on that revision at the tip of your current branch.