# How to have full controll on private bitbucket repo of other

Tags: bitbucket

I am working for client , he had asked me to push the code to bitbucket , he had provided me the write access but repo is private , I don't trust the client , is there any way like i can delete the code incase he had removed the access from repo ?

Comment: What does your contract with this client say?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no.

Any code you push is now available for them to view so long as they own the repo. You can try to [amend a commit](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history).

Ultimately they will still have local copies even if you do manage to make changes on bitbucket.

Possible duplicate of
[how-to-remove-specific-commits-from-git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46724078/how-to-remove-specific-commits-from-git)